# Filtering with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, multi-index

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this one:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1234)
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)], names=['letter', 'date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(midx), 1), index=midx)
```

That dataframe looks like this:

```
                        0
letter      date    
  a     2013-01-01  0.471435
        2013-01-02  -1.190976
        2013-01-03  1.432707
        2013-01-04  -0.312652
        2013-01-05  -0.720589
        2013-01-06  0.887163
  b     2013-01-01  0.859588
        2013-01-02  -0.636524
        2013-01-03  0.015696
        2013-01-04  -2.242685
        2013-01-05  1.150036
        2013-01-06  0.991946
  c     2013-01-01  0.953324
        2013-01-02  -2.021255
        2013-01-03  -0.334077
        2013-01-04  0.002118
        2013-01-05  0.405453
        2013-01-06  0.289092
```

What I want to do is to keep all rows based on a condition on **date** which depends on the **letter**. For instance,

- for **letter a**, I want to keep all rows such that **date is between "20130102" and "20130105" (included)**
- for **letter b**, I want to keep all rows such that **date == "20130103"**
- for **letter c**, I want to keep all rows such that **date is between "20130103" and "20130105" (included)**

All this information could be stored in a dictionary for instance.

```
dictionary = {"a": slice("20130102", "20130105"),
              "b": "20130103",
              "c": slice("20130103", "20130105")}
```

Is there an easy way to compute this with pandas? I did not find any information about such filtering.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `query`, it is designed for this kind of selection criteria.

If you slightly modify your `dictionary` you can generate your desired query with the help of a list comprehension:

```
In : dictionary
Out:
{'a': ('20130102', '20130105'),
 'b': ('20130103', '20130103'),
 'c': ('20130103', '20130105')}

In : df.query(
          ' or '.join("('{}' <= date <= '{}' and letter == '{}')".format(*(v + (k,))) 
          for k, v in dictionary.items())
         )
Out:
                          0
letter date
a      2013-01-02 -1.190976
       2013-01-03  1.432707
       2013-01-04 -0.312652
       2013-01-05 -0.720589
b      2013-01-03  0.015696
c      2013-01-03 -0.334077
       2013-01-04  0.002118
       2013-01-05  0.405453
```

For more information on what the query statement is actually doing, here's details on the list comprehension:

```
In : (' or '.join("('{}' <= date <= '{}' and letter == '{}')".format(*(v + (k,)))
          for k, v in dictionary.items()))
Out: "('20130102' <= date <= '20130105' and letter == 'a') or 
          ('20130103' <= date <= '20130105' and letter == 'c') or
          ('20130103' <= date <= '20130103' and letter == 'b')"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a kludgy way about this, but you could use the fact that

> passing a list of labels or tuples works similar to reindexing [[source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)]

and take advantage of `pd.Index.slice_indexer(start, stop)`, which lets you filter each index to between the specified dates.

```
>>> dictionary = {"a": ("20130102", "20130105"),
...               "b": "20130103",
...               "c": ("20130103", "20130105")}
... 
... 
... def get_idx_pairs():
...     for lvl0, lvl1 in df.index.groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0)).items():
...         dates = lvl1.levels[1]
...         dt = dictionary[lvl0]
...         if isinstance(dt, (tuple, list)):
...             slices = dates[dates.slice_indexer(dt[0], dt[1])]
...             for s in slices:
...                 yield (lvl0, s)
...         else:
...             yield (lvl0, dt)
... 
... 
... df.loc[list(get_idx_pairs())]
... 
                        0
letter date              
a      2013-01-02 -1.1910
       2013-01-03  1.4327
       2013-01-04 -0.3127
       2013-01-05 -0.7206
b      2013-01-03  0.0157
c      2013-01-03 -0.3341
       2013-01-04  0.0021
       2013-01-05  0.4055
```

For each "smaller" DatetimeIndex in `date`, you constrain that to the slices specified, then construct tuples of `(letter, date)` on which to index explicitly.

Alternatively, if you're okay with specifying the dates as tuples (for single dates, just repeat), you can condense the helper function a bit:

```
>>> dates = (("20130102", "20130105"),
...          ("20130103", "20130103"),
...          ("20130103", "20130105"))
... 
... def get_idx_pairs(df, dates):
...     letters = df.index.get_level_values(0)
...     for (k, v), (start, stop) in zip(df.index.groupby(letters).items(), dates):
...         dates = v.levels[1]
...         sliced = dates[dates.slice_indexer(start, stop)]
...         for s in sliced:
...             yield k, s
... 
... df.loc[list(get_idx_pairs(df, dates))]
... 
                        0
letter date              
a      2013-01-02 -1.1910
       2013-01-03  1.4327
       2013-01-04 -0.3127
       2013-01-05 -0.7206
b      2013-01-03  0.0157
c      2013-01-03 -0.3341
       2013-01-04  0.0021
       2013-01-05  0.4055
```

Answer (score 1):

With a small change to the original dictionary we can do this a little more succinctly. We can use `pd.IndexSlice` in a list comprehension and then `pd.concat`,

```
# add `-` to separate dates
dictionary = {"a": slice("2013-01-02", "2013-01-05"),
              "b": "2013-01-03",
              "c": slice("2013-01-03", "2013-01-05")}

dictionary = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items()))

idx_slices = [pd.IndexSlice[k, v] for k, v in dictionary.items()]

pd.concat([df.loc[idx, :] for idx in idx_slices])

Out[1]:
                     0
letter  date    
a       2013-01-02   -1.190976
        2013-01-03   1.432707
        2013-01-04   -0.312652
        2013-01-05   -0.720589
c       2013-01-03   -0.334077
        2013-01-04   0.002118
        2013-01-05   0.405453
b       2013-01-03   0.015696
```

If you wished to automate adding `-` you could use `datetime` as follows,

```
dt.datetime.strptime('20170121', '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Looks good, but is actually a hair slower than what I have now because of separate indexing operations and concatenation

Comment: @BradSolomon - I haven't timed it but I would bet your's is a little quicker. I think what I have is a lots more readable though. Not sure what OP wants to optimise for :)

Comment: Agreed on all points @josh.  Although I am the one who opened the bounty, wink wink

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to apply a function to a pandas DataFrameGroupBy object, this is an example:

```
dictionary = {"a": slice("20130102", "20130105"),
              "b": slice("20130103", "20130103"),
              "c": slice("20130103", "20130105")}

def date_condition(group, dictionary):
    return group.xs(group.name).loc[dictionary[group.name]]

df.groupby(level=0).apply(date_condition, dictionary)

Output[0]:
                          0
letter date                
a      2013-01-02 -1.190976
       2013-01-03  1.432707
       2013-01-04 -0.312652
       2013-01-05 -0.720589
b      2013-01-03  0.015696
c      2013-01-03 -0.334077
       2013-01-04  0.002118
       2013-01-05  0.405453
```

Note the slice for "b" repeats the date to enforce that `.loc` returns a DataFrame instead of a Series